# Implement value from datatable into datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm trying to change the color of 3 cells based on the corresponding database value attached to the physician initials. In other words, the physician has a specific color for the cell background when they view their patients. The database "physicians" has three columns (Physician Name, Initials, Color). Below is some of the code.

```
void PhysicianColorTreatPrep()

    {
        string ColorQuery = "SELECT * FROM physicians";

        SqlConnection connectionstring = new SqlConnection(constring);

        connectionstring.Open();

        DataTable dsDocColor = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapterDocColor = new SqlDataAdapter(ColorQuery, constring);
        adapterDocColor.Fill(dsDocColor);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridviewTreatmentPrep.Rows)
        {
            DataRow[] result = dsDocColor.Select("Color WHERE Initials = "+row.Cells["Primary_Onc"].Value.ToString()+"");

            row.Cells["Last_Name"].Style.BackColor =  //Color retrieved from datatable based on datagridview value
            row.Cells["First_Name"].Style.BackColor = //Color retrieved from datatable based on datagridview value
            row.Cells["Primary_Onc"].Style.BackColor = //Color retrieved from datatable based on datagridview value

        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code? Did you debug the code? What value you are getting in `result` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The `result` is actually returning a row from the datatable which is not correct. I need to return the string of the color from the datatable based on the "Primary_Onc" value and then place it on the `.BackColor` section in the bottom.

Comment: What are the values you are getting in datarow? You should retrieve color value from datarow and convert it to color.

Answer (score 0):

@ChetanRanpariya Thanks for asking the right questions. I managed to solve it. Below is the code.

```
DataRow[] result = dsDocColor.Select("Initials = '"+row.Cells["Primary_Onc"].Value.ToString()+"'");

            string DocColor = result[0][2].ToString();

            row.Cells["Last_Name"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(DocColor);

            row.Cells["First_Name"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(DocColor);
            row.Cells["Primary_Onc"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(DocColor);
```